# Find out if VoiceOver is enabled and set VoiceOver Focus on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, watchkit

I'm currently trying to make my game become more accessible by adding VoiceOver support. Everything is working fine on iOS, but I have some struggle with the watchOS Version. I need a way to find out, if VoiceOver is currently enabled to remove certain images based questions in the game. So ist there anything like:

```
UIAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()
```

in WatchKit?

And also, is it possible to move the accessibility focus to a certain element? Something comparable to:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, view);
```

Thanks, Klemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if it's running

```swift
let isVoiceOverOn: Bool = WKAccessibilityIsVoiceOverRunning()
if isVoiceOverOn {
    // do some VoiceOver stuff
} else {
    // do some stuff that does not make sense for VoiceOver
}
```

To find out when VoiceOver starts and stops observe:

```swift
WKAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusChanged
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!